# How to match a string that start with "." or "_"

Tags: scala

I need to match for a strings that describing filenames.

Can you suggest of how i can match only strings that dont start with "." or "_"

Thanks.

i've tried:

```
val x = "_pi"
val re = "^[\\._].*$".r
x match {
  case re(z) => println("false")
   case _ => println("true")
}
```

for printing "true" if the value don't match but it is not working
but it only prints false

Comment: What have you already tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please refer to stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (as cchantep just said) and add some code you already tried, describe what it does and how it doesnt match your criteria so we can help u to fix it.

We're not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions - `[\._]`
will match `.` or `_`. Try `^[\._].*$`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a regular expression you can call the built-in `startsWith` function on a String:

```
scala> def isBad(s: String): Boolean = s.startsWith("_") || s.startsWith(".")
isBad: (s: String)Boolean

scala> isBad(".foo")
res4: Boolean = true

scala> isBad("_bar")
res5: Boolean = true

scala> isBad("foobar")
res6: Boolean = true
```